# Bought a DVB PCI Card; my motherboard only has PCI 1x slot. Can the card fit in that slot?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, pci

Without thinking ahead I bought this TBS8922 DVB card:

[image]

After that I found that my motherboard has PCI 1x slots like below. Also, their end is opened.

[image]

Can above card plug into this socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [PCIe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) x1 slot. PCIe is a modern standard

The card is a [PCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI) card. This is a very old standard, and not physically compatible with PCIe. Some modern motherboards still come with PCI slots, but that's not what's in your photo.

It *is* possible to get [adapters](https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Slot-Extension/PCI-Express-to-PCI-Adapter-Card~PEX1PCI1), but that tends to be a bit messy and rather expensive. If the card isn't particularly expensive, you're probably better off buying a PCIe version of it.

Answer (score 2):

No, one is PCI the other looks like a pcie x1 slot.

https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Slot-Extension/PCI-Express-to-PCI-Adapter-Card~PEX1PCI1

These adapters exist, but a new tuner might be a similar in cost.